# Syncing Rails development environments on my two computers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby, macos, synchronization

So far I have been building my Rail app on a Mac OS X box using TextMate.

It's just me, so I haven't used Git. I have just opened and closed the code in the file system, used an AppleScript to take annotated snapshots at key moments, and let Time Machine take care of the rest.

I've just ordered a Windows laptop which I'll use for the same project. I'm hoping to sync everything automatically between the two computers.

I'm assuming I can sync the project itself using Git, Mercurial or SVN. (Regardless, I'd have to teach myself version control.) It would be nice to do this syncing via a server that provided free accounts for small private projects. It would also be nice if I could continue to use standard Open and Save dialogues in Mac OS X and Windows at the start and end of each chunk of work, instead of mucking around with version control commands. Any thoughts on how to make this is simple as possible?

Beyond that I'll have to sync the Rails version, the Ruby version, the available gems, and the available libraries like ImageMagick. Some of this I guess I can achieve by specifying the Rails version etc in various config files. Again, any thoughts?

If it was just you, a Mac and PC, what would be your ideal approach?

Comment: Take the plunge and teach yourself version control. I use it even on one machine.

Comment: http://bitbucket.org gives you 1 free private Mercurial repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite frankly there is no particularly easy way to achieve what you're after. Gems and libraries that need compiling, for instance, just can't be mirrored to another machine, especially a different OS.

However, I can provide you with an easier way to manage your projects if you don't want the hassle of Version control, which is [DropBox](http://www.getdropbox.com). I'm using it for one of my rails projects at the moment. Once you install the software, it creates a 'dropbox' folder on your machine. Any time you save a file into it, or update a file already in it, it's instantly uploaded to their free server, securely, and then downloaded onto each machine that have the software installed. This allows you to continue using the Open and Save dialogues you're used to while also keeping a history of each update you make to the server.

It is not an answer to Version Control, and it really isn't meant to be. Git and Mercurial are still worth learning, but it's a good middle ground and perfect when you don't need so much control. It's worth a look, even just for general backup.

P.S. I don't work for dropbox, i just love it.

Comment: Very cool. Thanks.

BTW, a gem-syncing gem sounds like a nice idea?

And I'm assuming I just fish around in various config files to have my app always use the same version of Rails and Ruby regardless of what's installed locally?

Comment: in the environment.rb file you can specify which rails version you want that app to use, and you can also specify a rails version when installing it onto a machine, like rails install --version=2.3.4 (or something to that effect) so yes, you can easily make each machine always use the same version anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to share my fix for this problem.  I am just beginning development in Rails and I am using two windows machines, one at work(teacher) and one at home.  I just want to play around with rails, but I want what I do at work/home to carry over to the other computer.  I was about to resort to dropbox when I finally stumbled on a solution for me.

### Problem: Syncing Rails Development on Two Computers with Git

### Solution

I used   *$ rails new app*  to create my project on PC1.  I then used GIT to *commit and push origin* repo to my github account.  The next day while at work, PC2, I used *git clone* to clone the project to my PC2.  When testing to see if my rails app worked, it did not.  Still on PC2 I went to the cmd.exe and ran *rails new app* on the same directory I had just made.  I went through and had to manually tell rails to skip duplicate files.  The end result was two working rails app, that share a github repo, and I can edit the code files on either PC and send them back and they work on the otherone.

For a person working solo on a project, I imagine the dropbox method is best, but I am trying to learn the whole development process so I wanted to get to a point where I was utilizing git.

Answer (score 2):

I really suggest opening a free account at Github.com and teaching yourself git. Learning the command line does not take long and once you start using it you can understand why the command line persists to this day.

Also, though I have not used it, there appears to be a good Git bundle for TextMate here:
http://gitorious.org/git-tmbundle

Comment: I presumed Git was for syncing application code, not the supporting libraries, gems, etc. Was I wrong?

Comment: If you freeze your gems as described here: http://gemsonrails.rubyforge.org/
you can then have your gems in your version control scheme.

Personally though I avoid freezing gems until I am at a point where I am almost ready for deployment.

By the way, this is exactly the strategy I am using for personal projects on a Mac and PC. Version control can be intimidating at first, but just like coding, once you start using it you will see that it is really quite simple, and even more importantly, it will save your bacon at some point in time.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that GIT is a great way to manage the versioning, but another way is to use a virtual machine. This means that you create your development environment under Ubuntu under VMWare or VirtualBox, and then copy the virtual image from one machine to another. This way you don't have to set everything up twice for the different operating systems, which can be a real pain. Using this technique means everything works the same under the Mac and Windows, and if you only have source code changes then you can still use GIT to keep the images up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd write in an update to this old question. I do indeed use Dropbox to sync code and git repositories.  I find this part very easy, and my code is never out of date.  The bigger problem is dealing with dependencies.  Nowadays, this is a lot easier than it used to be because when you sit down at your different machine your gemfile is synced and you can just 'bundle install'.  Pretty much anything you forget will throw an error, which is just like a friendly reminder that you have to rvm use this, or brew install that.  Stuff you already did on one machine, so it doesn't take too long to figure out.

About Git: Git doesn't sync anything.  It's used to save code ("commits") or save alternate versions ("branches").  It's also used to push to remote backups (like Github) or deployment services (like Heroku).  I used to hate it with a vigorous passion.  I understood that it was supposed to help me control versions, but didn't know how it worked and didn't trust it.  If I was working on a big update, I would copy the app directory to a backup.  After a few years, I wield git like a sushi chef wields his knife, deftly separating branches, merging, and occasionally resetting --HARD.

Learning Ruby/Rails has been a lot less work than learning to use tools like Git, RVM, and Homebrew, but they're also a big part of what makes programming in the 21st century fun and productive.